# Viewing an Array in Storage

Tags: view

Let's say Im creating a storage full of people as a person array. Can I retrieve and view all of the people from that storage at once or do I have to view each person separately in Remix?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a function to return a storage array as memory.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Tests {

    uint256[] store = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    function getStore() external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return store;
    }
}
```